# Difference between varchar2(10), varchar2(10 byte) and varchar2(10 char)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

I have been told by client to replace `varchar2(10 char)` by `varchar2(10 byte)`. I exactly don't know the difference in `varchar2(10),varchar2(10 char)` and `varchar2(10 byte)`. also could you please tell me in which scenario we should use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`VARCHAR2(10 byte)` will support up to 10 bytes of data, which could be as few as two characters in a multi-byte character sets.

`VARCHAR2(10 char)` could support as much as 40 bytes of information and will support to up 10 characters of data.

Varchar2(10) uses the current value of NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS to determine the limit for the string.

incase of byte, then it's 10 bytes.

incase of char, then it's 10 characters.

In multibyte character sets these can be different! So if NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = byte, you may only be able to store 5 characters in your varchar2.
So varchar2(10 char) is explicit. This can store up to 10 characters. Varchar2(10) is implicit. It may store 10 bytes or 10 characters, depending on the DB configuration.

[ocacle ask link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532325800346614530)

Comment: so is there any difference in varchar2(10) and varchar2(10 byte)?

Comment: @OnkarTiwari yes there is a difference and it depends on configuration

Comment: Zaynul.. does using varchar2(10 byte) will make any sense?

Comment: @OnkarTiwari actually it will depends on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

From asktom https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532325800346614530

> Varchar2(10) uses the current value of NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS to
>   determine the limit for the string.
>
> If this is byte, then it's 10 bytes.
>
> If it's char, then it's 10 characters.
>
> In multibyte character sets these can be different! So if
>   NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = byte, you may only be able to store 5
>   characters in your varchar2.
>
> So varchar2(10 char) is explicit. This can store up to 10 characters.
>   Varchar2(10) is implicit. It may store 10 bytes or 10 characters,
>   depending on the DB configuration.
>
> It's better to be explicit (10 char). Although all your prod/test/dev
>   databases should have the same setting for NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS,
>   doesn't mean they do...